# Adding template column to radgrid causes a grid UI issue

Tags: asp.net, telerik

Here is my grid, When i remove the template button the grid functions well, but when the template button is included the grid does not load well and the ui is somewhat destroyed, all the data appears in a chained string inside a box when the template button is in place:

```
<telerik:RadGrid OnItemCreated="gvClients_ItemCreated" runat="server" ID="gvClients" ClientSettings-EnablePostBackOnRowClick="true" CellSpacing="0" GridLines="None" Skin="Glow" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" AllowPaging="True" AllowSorting="True" OnSelectedIndexChanged="gvClients_SelectedIndexChanged" OnDataBound="gvClients_DataBound" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
<ClientSettings>
    <Selecting AllowRowSelect="True" />
</ClientSettings>
<MasterTableView DataKeyNames="id" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" HierarchyLoadMode="Client">
    <Columns>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="seniorId" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter seniorId column" HeaderText="seniorId" SortExpression="seniorId" UniqueName="seniorId" Visible="False">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="id" DataType="System.Int32" FilterControlAltText="Filter id column" HeaderText="תעדות זהות" ReadOnly="True" SortExpression="id" UniqueName="id">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="password" FilterControlAltText="Filter password column" HeaderText="סיסמא" SortExpression="password" UniqueName="password">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="fName" FilterControlAltText="Filter fName column" HeaderText="שם פרטי" SortExpression="fName" UniqueName="fName">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="lName" FilterControlAltText="Filter lName column" HeaderText="שם משפחה" SortExpression="lName" UniqueName="lName">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="mPhone" FilterControlAltText="Filter mPhone column" HeaderText="מספר טלפון" SortExpression="mPhone" UniqueName="mPhone">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="address" FilterControlAltText="Filter address column" HeaderText="כתובת" SortExpression="address" UniqueName="address">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="sc" DataType="System.Byte" FilterControlAltText="Filter sc column" HeaderText="sc" SortExpression="sc" UniqueName="sc" Visible="False">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="email" FilterControlAltText="Filter email column" HeaderText="אימייל" SortExpression="email" UniqueName="email">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="dateJoined" DataFormatString="{0:HH:mm dd-MM-yyyy}" DataType="System.DateTime" FilterControlAltText="Filter dateJoined column" HeaderText="תאריך הצטרפות" SortExpression="dateJoined" UniqueName="dateJoined">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridBoundColumn DataField="contract" FilterControlAltText="Filter contract column" HeaderText="קובץ חוזה" SortExpression="contract" UniqueName="contract">
            <ColumnValidationSettings>
                <ModelErrorMessage Text="" />
            </ColumnValidationSettings>
        </telerik:GridBoundColumn>
        <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn column" HeaderText="הורד קובץ" UniqueName="downloadbutton">
            <ItemTemplate>
                <telerik:RadButton ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Skin="Glow" Text="הורד קובץ" CommandArgument="<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" OnCommand="btnDownload_Command">
                </telerik:RadButton>
            </ItemTemplate>
        </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
    </Columns>
    <PagerStyle AlwaysVisible="True" />
</MasterTableView>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not know what the problem is but after creating a new solution and copying the same source files to the new solution the problem seems to have solved itself.

Thanks anyways!

Answer (score -1):

I added the templatecolumn just like below (without btnDownload_Command) and it rendered correctly. Could it be the special characters used in Text propery?

```
    <telerik:GridTemplateColumn FilterControlAltText="Filter TemplateColumn column" HeaderText="t" UniqueName="downloadbutton">
        <ItemTemplate>
            <telerik:RadButton ID="btnDownload" runat="server" Text="HeaderName" CommandArgument="<%#Container.ItemIndex %>" >
            </telerik:RadButton>
        </ItemTemplate>
    </telerik:GridTemplateColumn>
```

Comment: It is strange. On my other computer it works fine. But here specifically there is a problem.

Comment: I have minimized the problem, When i remove the button from the templatefield the grid works, when any sort of control of any type is added the issue returns. Very strange. never have i encountered this issue.

Comment: Were you able to reproduce the error in another webform? Or worse-case scenario, another project? Do both machines have the same version of the Telerik controls and the same DLLs?

Comment: The machine in which it works is of an older version, And i have tried recreating the error in another webform and it appeared again. Currently i am on telerik 2013 Q3

Comment: I was thinking the browser's compatibility view, I've had issued where the control was not rendered correctly with older browsers and/or browsers running in compatibility view. Also, try creating a new project. That way you would need to add the references once again. With the webform, if the DLL was referenced incorrectly in the project, the webform would suffer the same problem.

Comment: I just opened a new solution as you suggested and it now works great! I really have not idea what the problem was, probably had to do to some references or DLLs as you said, but either way it now works and that what's important.